KDE Application Menu Bookmark
I'm trying to see if it is possible to create a menu item in Kubuntu to open a new Firefox window that opens a specific bookmark. Basically the MS Teams PWA app in the store doesn't work with a camera (or at least not with mine), but it works fine in Firefox, so I'm trying to create a 'Microsoft Teams' menu item that just opens a new Firefox window and goes straight to that URL. I've got as far as going into the menu editor, copying the Firefox app, renaming it and changing the icon, but I can't figure out any way to have it go to a specific URL. Does anyone know if this is even possible?
